# Axis bug on Pandas groupby boxplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

The head of my Pandas dataframe , `df`, is shown below:

```
  count1  count2  totalcount  season
0       3      13          16       1
1       8      32          40       1
2       5      27          32       1
3       3      10          13       1
4       0       1           1       1
```

I'd like to make boxplots of `count1`, `count2`, and `totalcount`, grouped by `season` (there are 4 seasons) and have each set of box plots show up on their own subplot in a single figure.

When I do this with only two of the columns, say `count1` and `count2`, everything looks great.

```
df.boxplot(['count1', 'count2'], by='season')
```

[image]

But when I add `totalcount` to the mix, the axis limits go haywire.

```
df.boxplot(['count1', 'count2', 'totalcount'], by='season')
```

[image]

This happens irregardless of the order of the columns. I realize there are several ways around this problem, but it would be much more convenient if this worked properly.

Am I missing something? Is this a known bug in Pandas? I wasn't able to find anything in my first pass of the Pandas bug reports.

I'm using Pandas 0.14.0 and matplotlib 1.3.1.

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried to upgrade your pandas/matplotlib packages?

I'm using Pandas 0.13.1 + Matplotlib 1.2.1 and this is the plot I get:

[image: boxplot]

```
In [31]: df
Out[34]: 
    count1  count2  totalcount  season
0        3      13          16       1
1        8      32          40       1
2        5      27          32       1
3        3      10          13       1
4        0       1           1       1
5        3      13          16       2
6        8      32          40       2
7        5      27          32       3
8        3      10          13       3
9        0       1           1       4
10       3      10          13       4
11       3      13          16       4

[12 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Interesting - I'm actually using Pandas 0.14.0 and matplotlib 1.3.1.

Comment: @Greg, indeed. I upgraded to your versions and the issue is there.